# How to sync DB2 databases/tables located on different hosts?

Tags: database, db2, synchronization

What kind of strategy we could use to sync DB2 database and/or tables located on different hosts?

I'm searching for a strategy that I could configure some parameters (like host, port, etc.) and just write a table name. After this the tool, script, or other strategy, should sync the tables cross the hosts.

For MySQL I know a tool that do something like this ([pt-table-sync](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-table-sync.html)). But, what we can do for DB2?

If is a tool, would be important that it is a free one.

Answer (score 2):

IBM has three replication methods:

- Change Data Capture: is the most versatile product as far as sources and targets are concerned. Sources for CDC include Oracle, DB2 (on any OS, mainframe or distributed, i/z/p/xSeries), MS SQL Server, Informix, SolidDB and Sybase. Targets include all of the sources as well as Teradata, Netezza, DataStage, CognosNow, Greenplum, MQ and JMS.
- Q Replication: is the most limited option in that it requires a DB2 or Oracle source. In this case the DB2 can be z/OS or LUW based DB2, but not iSeries. Oracle on all platforms is supported. Q Replication can replicate to limited non-DB2 targets including Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server, Informix Dynamic Server and Sybase
- SQL Replication: has a wider range of sources and targets. DB2 (including iSeries databases), Oracle, Informix Dynamic Server, Microsoft SQL Server and Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise can all be used as sources and targets. In addition Informix Extended Parallel Server and Teradata are supported as targets only.

CDC and Q Replication as part of InfoSphere Replication Server are priced by Processor Value Unit, so the number of processors where you are running the applications, sources and targets, will determine your price.

SQL Replication running as Heterogeneous Replication (non-DB2 sources or targets) is also part of InfoSphere Replication Server, and priced accordingly. SQL Replication between DB2 family databases is free on LUW platforms.

Answer (score 0):

All paid DB2 editions for Linux, UNIX and Windows (i.e., everything except DB2 Express-C) include [Homogeneous SQL replication](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSTRGZ_10.2.1/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.db.repl.sqlrepl.doc/topics/iiyrscncsqlreplovu.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F9-2-1) functionality that you can implement to keep tables in sync.

Answer (score 0):

[SymmetricDS](http://symmetricds.org) is an open source java tool for synchronizing databases.  It supports DB2 and a variety of others for Heterogeneous SQL Replication as well.